# File Upload - send data chunks to back-end server from Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, file-upload

I have 3 Nginx servers(replicas) and another 3 node servers(replicas).

Nginx has the upstream as follows

```
upstream wsbackend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
    listen 8021;

    location / {       
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header X-FILE $request_body_file;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://wsbackend;
    }
}
```

Now, when I am uploading a file sized 50 MB, node.js is getting the file as a whole. I want to receive the file as chunks as I am uploading  multipart form data from my client(browser).

How will I get chunks in node.js from Nginx when I upload a file?

Comment: The nginx is completely irrelevant here. The important part is node.js code. What framework or module do you use?

Comment: I don't know why Nginx is irrelevant here. Nginx is not sending the file as chunks to node server is the problem.